# Aligning text to the bottom line of a rectangle

Tags: circuitikz, alignment

In my circuit, I added rectangles to represent the different blocks that compose it. I would like the name of each block to appear at the bottom of the rectangle and centered on the rectangle. Currently I am forced to place with "real" coordinates that I get by fumbling around but it's not a very clean way.
My various tests only made the text appear along the diagonal of the drawn rectangle.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[en amp](aop1){AO1};
\draw (aop1.+) 
    to[short] ++(0,-2) node[ground](GND){};
\draw (aop1.-) 
    --++(0,1.5) coordinate (in-1) 
    --++(-2,0)  node[npn, photo, anchor=E](photo){} ;
\draw (photo.C) 
    --++(-2,0) coordinate (pile) 
    to[battery2] (pile|-GND);
\draw (in-1) 
    to [vR, mirror] (in-1 -|aop1.out) 
    to[short] (aop1.out);

\draw (GND)
    to[short] (GND-|pile);
   
%Tracé des blocs   
\coordinate (rect1haut) at ($(pile)+(-0.5,0.5)$);
\coordinate (rect1bas) at ($(GND)+(-1,-1)$);
\draw [dashed] (rect1bas)  
    rectangle (rect1haut);
\path (-4,-3.6) node{Détecteur}
    (-4,-4) node{d'obscurité};
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: an easy way is to reference the coordinate already created with the name `rect1bas` and create a node with reference to this coordinate `node[] {$m$}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fit` library and node for rectangle:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,
                fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[en amp](aop1){AO1};
\draw (aop1.+)
    to[short] ++(0,-2) node[ground](GND){};
\draw (aop1.-)
    --++(0,1.5) coordinate (in-1)
    --++(-2,0)  node[npn, photo, anchor=E](photo){} ;
\draw (photo.C)
    --++(-2,0) coordinate (pile)
    to[battery2] (pile|-GND);
\draw (in-1)
    to [vR, mirror] (in-1 -|aop1.out)
    to[short] (aop1.out);

\draw (GND)
    to[short] (GND-|pile);

%Tracé des blocs
\node   [draw, densely dashed, inner xsep=1.5em,
         fit=(pile) (photo |- GND),
         label={[align=center]below: Détecteur\\ d'obscurité}] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Corrected size of dashed rectangle by changing coordinates in `fit`, consequently now are old coordinates definition is removed.

**Addendum:**

I think the your sheme has an error, so (for exercise) I rewrite your code that it be correct and a bit shorter and resulted sheme (to my opinion) nicer:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,
                fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)       node[en amp]    (ao1) {AO1} 
        (ao1.+)     to[short] ++    (0,-2)  
                    node[red, ground] (GND) {}
        (ao1.-)     |- ++ (-1,1.5)  node[npn, photo, anchor=E] (photo) {}
        (ao1.out)   to [short]  (ao1.out |- photo.E)
                    to [vR,invert]     (photo.E -| ao1.-)
                    to [short] (ao1.-) 
        (photo.C)   -- ++ (-2,0) coordinate (aux)
                    to[battery2,name=pile] (aux |- GND);
%Tracé des blocs
\node   [draw, densely dashed, inner xsep=1.5em,
         fit=(photo) (pile |- GND),
         label={[align=center]below: Détecteur\\ d'obscurité}] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The drawing of the rectangle with your method is larger than with the commande `\ draw () rectangle ()` : what is this due to?

Comment: @Nicolas Add `inner sep=0pt` to the options of the `\node` command. Better?

Comment: @gernot, thank you for comment. I assume, that this is not so important :-(

Comment: @Nicolas, see edited answer. Does rectangle now has correct size?

Comment: @Zarko : it's not very important, it's just that it questioned me ! With the option `inner sep=0pt`, the sizee is the same.
 Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
%Tracé des blocs   
\coordinate (rect1haut) at ($(pile)+(-0.5,0.5)$);
\coordinate (rect1bas) at ($(GND)+(-1,-1)$);
\draw [dashed,] (rect1bas) 
    rectangle (rect1haut);
\node[below=4cm]at ($(rect1haut)!0.5!(rect1bas)$)() {z};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the dashed line as a node with dashed border and use the `label` option.

```
%Tracé des blocs   
\node[dashed,draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=6.5cm,
    label={[align=center]below:Détecteur\\d'obscurité}]
    at ($(pile)+(1,-2.9)$) {};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[en amp](aop1){AO1};
\draw (aop1.+) 
    to[short] ++(0,-2) node[ground](GND){};
\draw (aop1.-) 
    --++(0,1.5) coordinate (in-1) 
    --++(-2,0)  node[npn, photo, anchor=E](photo){} ;
\draw (photo.C) 
    --++(-2,0) coordinate (pile) 
    to[battery2] (pile|-GND);
\draw (in-1) 
    to [vR, mirror] (in-1 -|aop1.out) 
    to[short] (aop1.out);

\draw (GND)
    to[short] (GND-|pile);
   
%Tracé des blocs   
\node[dashed,draw,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=6.5cm,
    label={[align=center]below:Détecteur\\d'obscurité}]
    at ($(pile)+(1,-2.9)$) {};
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I prefer Zarko's answer that you completed ;)